# Running All Client Only Outlook Rules

Tags: vba, outlook

Goal: Run all my client only rules. Total of 269.

Problem: Code runs a single rule at a time not all.

Solution Attempts/Ideas Tried: An array for my rules to run in a list. Ran into a few issues as I don't have much experience in compiling arrays.

```vb
Sub RunAllInboxRules()
Dim st As Outlook.Store
Dim myRules As Outlook.rules
Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
Dim runrule As String
Dim rulename As String
'Rule name intended to run
rulename = "ABC 123"

Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
Set myRules = st.GetRules
Set cf = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
For Each rl In myRules
If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then
If rl.name = rulename Then
rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=cf
runrule = rl.name
End If
End If
Next
ruleList = "Rule was executed correctly:" & vbCrLf & runrule
MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: Whatever_Finished"
Set rl = Nothing
Set st = Nothing
Set myRules = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check the rule name each time you iterate over all rules in the collection:

```
Sub RunAllInboxRules()
 Dim st As Outlook.Store
 Dim myRules As Outlook.rules
 Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
 Dim rulelist As String
 Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
 Set myRules = st.GetRules
 Set cf = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
 For Each rl In myRules
    rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=cf
    ruleList = "Rule was executed correctly:" & vbCrLf & rl.Name
    MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: Whatever_Finished"
 Next     
 Set rl = Nothing
 Set st = Nothing
 Set myRules = Nothing
End Sub
```

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee814736(v=office.14)) article helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to split the rules up? Say I want to execute rules Half the rules in one folder and then run the other half in a different folder.The code you provided worked fine since the last rules in the list were applicable to the folder I was in. Other than having to hold down 'enter' till all the rules finished running.

Comment: You can use the `for` loop instead of `For Each` and iterate over first half and then on the second. The `myRules.Count` property will help you with that task.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply client-only rules with `.IsLocalRule`.

```
Private Sub RunClientOnlyRules()

Dim st As store
Dim myRules As rules
Dim myFolder As Folder
Dim rl As Rule

Set st = Session.DefaultStore
Set myRules = st.GetRules
Set myFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

For Each rl In myRules
    If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then
        If rl.IsLocalRule Then
            rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=myFolder
        End If
    End If
Next

ExitRoutine:
    Set st = Nothing
    Set myRules = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing
    Set rl = Nothing

MsgBox "Done."

End Sub
```